# Why the S3 web hosting redirects me to an unknwn location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

I want to host a static web site on AWS, to do so I build my project on my computer. It's an angular project, my dist/ directory contains all the files I need to upload. I have a specific bucket named accordingly to my registered host name.

I configured route 53 to link my DNS name to my S3 bucket, accordingly with amazon tutorial.

I configured my S3 to be a web host, the ACL is fine, so are the permissions and the CORS access, and the redirection rule to get rid of "#/". 
After 30min of impatient wait, I connect to my registered DNS name, let say 'myexample.com', and I can see my website, everything's great.

Now time flies and I want to change everything. I delete every data in my bucket, and put an other website files inside.

Here the problem starts: when I go to 'myexample.com' it's redirected to a strange url : "pictureStatic/#/"
It's strange, but it's actually the name of my repository on my computer. It is also the name I used in my "Redirection rules" configuration in my S3 bucket, because of my previous hosted website. So I delete the redirection rule, but the redirection stays. 
my redirection rules where : 
"HostName": "PictureStatic"
"Protocol": "http"
"ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "#/"

I think of a route 53 problem or something like that so I re-do everything from scratch :

I copy my files on my computer in another directory and get rid of any "picurestatic" word anywhere. 
I build my project 
I upload the built files in an other test bucket, and configure it to be a web host. I make no link to the route53 area, but instead I use the direct url to the bucket: my web site works perfectly well

I delete my bucket "myexample.com" named accordingly to my registered name (mandatory for my route 53 configuration) and create it back from scratch, with exactly the same configuration of my test bucket, except the permission is configured for my bucket.

The CORS is :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>GET</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>PUT</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The ACL is : Everyone on read object/permission object

The permissions are :

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myexample.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I then want to access to my bucket directly without route53, so via : 
myexample.com.s3-website-MyRegion.amazonaws.com

It still redirect me to my old "pictureStatic/#/" even if my other test bucket works fine with the same actions.

I don't understand how to get rid of this redirection. It's note route53 as I don't use it in my test, and the point is that I have to fix my bucket named "myexample.com" otherwise I dan't use my registered DNS name anymore, because route53 force them to have the same name.

I tried to configure my bucket "myexample.com" to redirect to my test bucket, but it didn't change anything.

Someone has an idea of the reason of this redirection please ?

Comment: Where is AngularJs here.

Comment: Indeed. It's an angular project, but useless to tag it there. The tag has been removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found the reason of the problem, and it's kinda stupid. 
When I use my browser in private mode, there is no problem anymore, so it's more a problem of local cache on my browser than a problem on my application.